# При повторном нажатии на кнопку не запускается скрипт

Tags: jquery

Есть скрипт, весь код:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            var selEdit = $("#edit<?echo $table['id'];?>");
            selEdit.on("click", function () {
                    var id = "<?echo $table['id'];?>";
                    var name = "<?echo $table['name'];?>";
                    var surename = "<?echo $table['surename'];?>";
                    var company = "<?echo $table['company'];?>";
                    var department = "<?echo $table['department'];?>";
                    var post = "<?echo $table['post'];?>";
                    var selName = $("#name<?echo $table['id'];?>");
                    var selSurename = $("#surename<?echo $table['id'];?>");
                    var selImg = $("#img<?echo $table['id'];?>");
                    /***------------------------Замена полей на поля для
 ввода----------------------------***/
                    selName.html('<input id="name2<?echo $table['
                        id '];?>"
 type="text" size="<?echo
 mb_strlen($table['
                        name '],'
                        utf - 8 ');?>"
 value="<?echo $table['
                        name '];?>">');
                    selSurename.html('<input id="surename2<?echo $table['
                        id '];?>"
 type="text" size="<?echo
 mb_strlen($table['
                        surename '],'
                        utf - 8 ');?>"
 value="<?echo
 $table['
                        surename '];?>">');
                    /***------------------------Замена полей на поля для
 ввода----------------------------***/

                    selImg.html('<img src="images/ticons/accept.png"
 id="accept<?echo $table['
                        id '];?>"
 title="Сохранить">&nbsp&nbsp<img
 src="images/ticons/delete.png"
 id="cancel<?echo $table['
                        id '];?>"
 title="Отмена">');
                    $("#accept<?echo $table['id'];?>").click(function () {
                            var n = $("#name2<?echo
 $table['id'];?>").val();
                            var sn = $("#surename2<?echo $table['id'];?>").val();
                            alert(n + " " + sn);
                            //if(name!==){ $.post("" , {},function(){if(){alert('Пользователь
                            добавлен!');window.location.reload();}
 }); }
                 });
                  $("#cancel<?echo $table['
                            id '];?>").click(function(){
                  /***------------------------Возврат
 полей----------------------------***/
                 selName.html(' <? echo $table['name']; ?> ');
                 selSurename.html(' <? echo $table['surename']; ?> ');
                 selImg.html(' < img src = "images/ticons/cog_edit.png"
                            title = "Изменить"
                            id = "edit<?echo
 $table['id'];?>" / > & nbsp & nbsp < img
                            src = "images/ticons/cross.png"
                            id = "delete<?echo $table['id'];?>"
                            title = "Удалить" / > ');
                 /***------------------------Возврат
 полей----------------------------***/
                 });                 
             });
             });
</script>
```

для того что бы вы меня поняли нужны пара строк:
при клике:

```
var selEdit = $("#edit<?echo $table['id'];?>");
selEdit.on("click",function(){
```

происходит вставка кода:

```
selName.html('<input id="name2<?echo $table['id'];?>" type="text" size="<?echo mb_strlen($table['name'],'utf-8');?>" value="<?echo $table['name'];?>">');
selSurename.html('<input id="surename2<?echo $table['id'];?>" type="text" size="<?echo mb_strlen($table['surename'],'utf-8');?>" value="<?echo $table['surename'];?>">');
```

после того как пользователь совершил манипуляции со страницей, он нажимает на кнопочку и возвращает (вставляет) то что было до вставки кода:

```
selName.html('<?echo $table['name'];?>');
selSurename.html('<?echo $table['surename'];?>');
```

включая ту кнопку которая активировала весь этот процес:

```
selImg.html('<img src="images/ticons/cog_edit.png" title="Изменить" id="edit<?echo $table['id'];?>"/>&nbsp&nbsp<img src="images/ticons/cross.png" id="delete<?echo $table['id'];?>" title="Удалить" />');
```

то есть, при нажатии на кнопку(**изменить**), обычные текстовые поля в таблице меняются на поля для ввода текста, и меняется сама кнопка которая была нажата на другие типо сохранить и отменить, после нажатия сохранить возращаются обычные текстовые строки и возвращается кнопка **изменить**, но при повторном ее нажатии скрипт не запускается.
ХЕЕЛПП ПЛИЗ

Comment: @DDigital, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Писать php-код в js-скрипте плохая практика. Клиент отдельно, сервер отдельно.

Comment: Да у вас тут черт ногу сломит. Ужасное форматирование кода.